# Download pdf file from wikipedia

Tags: http, haskell, haskell-tagsoup

Wikipedia provides a link (left side on Print/export) on every article to download the article as pdf. I wrote a small Haskell script which first gets the Wikipedia link and output the rendering link. When I am giving the rendering url as input, I am getting empty tags but the same url in browser provides download link.

Could someone please tell me how to solve this problem? Formated code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/OtfIx).

```
import Network.HTTP
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Data.Maybe

parseHelp :: Tag String -> Maybe String 
parseHelp ( TagOpen _ y ) = if any ( \( a , b ) -> b == "Download a PDF version of this wiki page" ) y 
                      then Just $  "http://en.wikipedia.org" ++   snd (   y !!  0 )
                   else Nothing


parse :: [ Tag String ] -> Maybe String
parse [] = Nothing 
parse ( x : xs ) 
   | isTagOpen x = case parseHelp x of 
              Just s -> Just s 
              Nothing -> parse xs
   | otherwise = parse xs


main = do 
    x <- getLine 
    tags_1 <-  fmap parseTags $ getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP ( getRequest x ) --open url
    let lst =  head . sections ( ~== "<div class=portal id=p-coll-print_export>" ) $ tags_1
        url =  fromJust . parse $ lst  --rendering url
    putStrLn url
    tags_2 <-  fmap parseTags $ getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP ( getRequest url )
    print tags_2
```

Comment: For those who want to download pdf directly and dont know how to do it, please refer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try requesting the URL through some external tool like `wget`, you will see that Wikipedia does not serve up the result page directly. It actually returns a `302 Moved Temporarily` redirect.

When entering this URL in a browser, it will be fine, as the browser will follow the redirect automatically. `simpleHTTP`, however, will not. `simpleHTTP` is, as the name suggests, rather simple. It does not handle things like cookies, SSL or redirects.

You'll want to use the [`Network.Browser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/latest/doc/html/Network-Browser.html) module instead. It offers much more control over how the requests are done. In particular, the [`setAllowRedirects`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/latest/doc/html/Network-Browser.html#v%3asetAllowRedirects) function will make it automatically follow redirects.

Here's a quick and dirty function for downloading an URL into a `String` with support for redirects:

```
import Network.Browser

grabUrl :: String -> IO String
grabUrl url = fmap (rspBody . snd) . browse $ do
    -- Disable logging output
    setErrHandler $ const (return ())
    setOutHandler $ const (return ())

    setAllowRedirects True
    request $ getRequest url
```